# Matrix Size in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, size, dimension, curves

I have two curves with sizes:

```
size(A) = 1 312 and size(B) = 312
```

When subtsracting A from B, I got this error message

> Error using ==> minus Matrix dimensions must agree.

Can this error be attributed to the order of the matrices where the values of A = 1 312 and that of B = 312 1?

Answer (score 2):

Those matrices are not the same dimensions, try subtracting A' from B (A transpose).